# Change Form Select Multiple Highlight Color

Tags: forms, css, select, drop-down-menu

I'm putting together this form for a client project, using ExpressionEngine and Freeform Pro, and for some reason, I'm getting this green highlight on my select multiple field:

[image: sorry, I can't post a link]

(sorry, I can't post a link)

I'm not finding the green anywhere in the CSS. Where might it be defined, and how could I change it? I'm not aware of any CSS that affects the highlight color of form elements.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually the highlight color setting in the OSX System Preferences. Apparently, it cannot be overridden in CSS3.